# ThinkPad T470p snd-hda-intel: headphones work but no onboard sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, thinkpad, 20.04

My laptop is running a clean install of focal fossa 20.04 and I can't hear anything from my onboard speakers. Fortunately, my headphones do work. The aux port is okay.

```
bingo@pinkdad:~$ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: pinkdad Kernel: 5.4.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20J6CTO1WW v: ThinkPad T470p 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20J6CTO1WW serial: <superuser/root required> 
  UEFI: LENOVO v: R0FET51W (1.31 ) date: 01/07/2020 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel CM238 HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-26-generic
```

I've been playing with `alsamixer` and `pavucontrol` and the settings GUI to make sure nothing is muted and it's all turned up.
[image]
This seems to be affected by modifying `sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` appropriately and rebooting.

Here are the options I've tried:

- `options snd-hda-intel model=generic`
- `options snd-hda-intel model=ALC298`
- `options snd-hda-intel model=auto`

No success yet on my new install of 20.04. Any help / ideas here so appreciated. All worked well on previous versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @xiota omg so many options, i'll post if any succeed
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html#alc22x-23x-25x-269-27x-28x-29x-and-vendor-specific-alc3xxx-models

Comment: `options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad` didn't work, looked so hopeful too

Comment: hey @xiota thanks you are on it! i tried and no prevail. headphones work perfectly, so that's wonderful. i might be waiting for some new versions to come out

Comment: nice direction @xiota, 20.04 ships with 5.4.x. i might gamble on latest kernels having bugs fixed

Comment: @xiota i know auto is broken on 20.04 since it makes me choose `Configuration` either stereo or `surround 4.0 output`

Answer (score 2):

Add this line -

`options snd-hda-intel model=auto`

at the end of

`/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

and `reboot` the system.

it started working for me. Apparently, we need to point out alsamixer to use auto-detection between speaker and headphones.

Comment: my t470p, now running `20.10`, automatically selects `Output Device: Speakers - Built-in Audio`, however i can't get the speakers to make a sound

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem with latitude 3510 running ubuntu 18.04: no sound in headphones while speaker works fine.

snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 solved issue